# Mac Webcam not working on skype for linux

Tags: 17.10, skype, webcam, macbook-air

I am trying to get skype for linux working, however it is not finding the built in webcam that my MacBook Air came with.

I ran lsusb and received this as my output:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 05ac:0291 Apple, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 05ac:828f Apple, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0a5c:4500 Broadcom Corp. BCM2046B1 USB 2.0 Hub (part of BCM2046 Bluetooth)
Bus 001 Device 017: ID 058f:6387 Alcor Micro Corp. Flash Drive
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

and uname -a output:

```
Linux br-MacBookAir 4.13.0-36-generic #40-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 16 20:07:48 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I followed this guide: https://github.com/patjak/bcwc_pcie/wiki/Get-Started#get-started-on-ubuntu and installed the firmware package already.

I also installed cheese and cheese says that there is no device found.

Comment: Does your webcam work with Cheese?

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi No it says that it is not found.

Comment: Is this a dual boot? Did you remove OSX and replace with Linux? Are you running VM?

Comment: I removed OSX and replaced it with Ubuntu

Comment: What does lsmod say?